# Problems importing grass.script into PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, gis, pydev

I am trying to do grass scripting in Eclipse and i follow the instructions outlined in [this](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Using_Eclipse_to_develop_GRASS_Python_programs) page. I think i have everything configured however when i try to import grass.script i get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nesic/Desktop/grass_dev/Simulacije/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    import grass.script as grass
  File "/usr/lib/grass64/etc/python/grass/script/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core   import *
  File "/usr/lib/grass64/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 38, in <module>
    gettext.install('grasslibs', os.path.join(os.getenv("GISBASE"), 'locale'), unicode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 67, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.getenv("GISBASE")` most likely returns `None`, because the envorinment variable `GISBASE` is not set. That then leads to the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'` you're seeing.

Try setting `GISBASE` according to http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/variables.html:

> GISBASE
>
> ```
> directory where GRASS lives. This is set automatically by the startup script.
> ```

(BTW, if you don't know about it already, there's also [gis.stackexchange.org](http://gis.stackexchange.org))

Comment: Thank you! No i didn't know about the gis specific one.